# Where can I find beer for Letitia?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

There's an informant in Detroit and the game has an option to give her beer, but apparently beggars **can** be choosers and she will only take "Mahara Jah Hot Devil Ale".

Where can I find that beer and what are the advantages for giving it to her?

Comment: After giving her a certain amount of the beer (5 of the smaller white canned beer I think), I _believe_ that you'll be able to bribe her for information for cheap.  Once I realized that she needs a certain amount, I already got all the information I could get from her.  There was nothing else that she had to offer at that point.

Comment: There's a **beer** quest and I _missed_ it?

Comment: Which mission is this part of? Is it the first or second detroit visit?

Comment: @Coomie: It's not really much of a mission. She just digs through a trashcan near the train station (first and second detroit visit I think) and if you talk to her she gives you tips and codes for money.

Comment: I don't see her on the second visit. The area she's in in the first part is blocked off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a reason why Letitia was digging around a garbage can when you first see her.

You can find the beer she wants (Mahara Jah Hot Devil Ale) in those if you search in enough trash bins.  There were also a few to be grabbed in the Milwaukee plant in the first mission.

[image]
[image]

As for why anyone would want to throw away unopened beer, I have no clue, except maybe that perhaps she has horrible taste in beer and that stuff tastes horrible.

When you give her 4 beers, she gives you the code to Seurat's stash by the basketball court.  If you knock her out, you'll find the pocket secretary on her with those codes.  (and all your money back)

Comment: But can you confirm what happens if you give her enough beers?

Comment: @Jeff Mercado, I added that part